# ArrayList to XML

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

I am trying to take the contents of an ArrayList and put them into an XML file. Does anyone have a quick,clean and easy solution to this rather that having to use streams and handle exceptions?

For more information, Here is the code I have currently I am getting problem with it, one of which its not creating the file.

```
    package ie.wit.io;

import ie.wit.abs.Device;
import ie.wit.abs.Device;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FileHandler
{
    private FileOutputStream outByteStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream OOStream;
    private FileInputStream inByteStream;
    private ObjectInputStream OIStream;
    private File aFile;

    public void setUpFile()
    {

        aFile = new File("data.xml");

    }

    public boolean isFileEmpty()
    {
        return (aFile.length() <= 0);
    }





    public void writeToFile(ArrayList<Device> team) 
    {
     try
     {

      outByteStream = new FileOutputStream(aFile);
      OOStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outByteStream);

      OOStream.writeObject(team);

      outByteStream.close();
      OOStream.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I/O Error" + e + "\nPlease Contact your Administrator :-)");
     }
    }

currentClass)
    public ArrayList<Device> readFromFile()
    {
        ArrayList<Device> temp = null;

    try
     {
      inByteStream = new FileInputStream(aFile);
      OIStream = new ObjectInputStream(inByteStream);

      if(!this.isFileEmpty())
          temp = (ArrayList<Device>)OIStream.readObject();

      inByteStream.close();
      OIStream.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I/O Error" + e + "\nPlease Contact your Administrator :-)");
     }

     catch(Exception e)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"General Error" + e + "\nPlease Contact your Administrator :-)");
     }

    return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you will have to use streams.

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries to do that task.

Here is what I'm doing so far. Edit as per your requirement.

```
  protected String getDocmentsAsString(List<News> documentsListByIndex) {
        if(documentsListByIndex.size()>0){
        try {
            XStream xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
            xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
            xstream.alias("news", News.class);
            return xstream.toXML(documentsListByIndex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Im using http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuilder and generate the XML yourself.. It depends on how many items you want to convert. The fastest way is just pushing out the XML data using a StringBuilder.

Comment: It also depends on how complex your items are. The code can become quite hard to maintain if you have complex items.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to:

1. create a XSD
2. generate JAXB Java classes (e.g. using a [Maven Plugin](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home))
3. create instances of the JAXB Java classes and fill up the data
4. [marshal the JAXB Java classes to XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/basic.html)